# DatePicker does not commit value if focus is changed within ChangeListener

Tags: java, javafx

> **The following issue is occurring with JDK 1.8 (8u231), Windows 10**

I have a `DatePicker` setup with a listener that shows an `Alert` when the value changes.  However, as soon as the `Alert` is displayed, the `datePicker.valueProperty()` reverts back to its original value.

This does not appear to be "working as designed" and multiple other developers have confirmed the issue does not exist in later versions of Java.

Here is a MCVE to demonstrate:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.DatePicker;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class DatePickerCommit extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        // Simple Interface
        VBox root = new VBox(10);
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(10));

        DatePicker datePicker = new DatePicker();

        // Add listener on DatePicker
        datePicker.valueProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {

            if (newValue != null) {

                // Show an Alert
                Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.WARNING);
                alert.setContentText("You selected " + newValue);
                alert.show();
                alert.setY(alert.getY()+100);
            }

        });

        root.getChildren().add(datePicker);

        // Show the stage
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Sample");
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

The `Alert` itself **does** display the correct date, but the `DatePicker` `valueProperty()` reverts back to `null`, as seen in this screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Using IntelliJ's debugger, I can confirm the `datePicker.valueProperty()` is set to 'null' as soon as `alert.show()` (or `alert.showAndWait()`) is called.

> **Closest Potential Known Bugs:**

I was able to find a few known bugs that seem to be related, but they have all been marked as resolved as of 8u73 (possible regression?):

- [JDK-8097293 : [DatePicker] Does not change to new selected value if modal window is shown in DatePicker-action](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8097293)
- [JDK-8138730 : [ComboBox, DatePicker] Value doesn't update when focus is lost](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8138730)
- [JDK-8136838 : [ComboBox, DatePicker] Value doesn't update when focus is lost](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8136838)

Comment: I am not getting any problems. `Product Version: Apache NetBeans IDE 11.2
Java: 13; OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 13+33
Runtime: OpenJDK Runtime Environment 13+33
System: Windows 10 version 10.0 running on amd64; Cp1252; en_US (nb)`

Comment: Great. Might be a bug in Java 8?

Comment: Just to be clear. You are saying that the alert data is different from the selected date?

Comment: No. The Alert shows the selected date. But the DatePicker value has reverted to null.

Comment: Are you saying that the `Textfield's` date of the `DatePicker` is different than the `Alert` date?

Comment: Correct. The TextField shows no value at all (moving the Alert out of the way so I can see the value of the DatePicker).

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. Then yes, I am getting the expected behavior. I see the same date in the `DatePicker's` `TextField` that is in the `Alert`.

Comment: I am on java 8 and I cannot reproduce.  Im mildly confused by your working but when the `Alert` shows and I move it the same date is displayed behind it(on the `DatePicker`'s `TextField`) as the `Alert` is showing

Comment: That is odd. I'm on 8u231. You too?

Comment: can reproduce on 1.8.0u152 - so looks like a bug that's fixed later ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am able to reproduce this issue in the JDK version I am currently working. So on investigation, the root cause is getting focus on to new stage (or losing focus from DatePicker) before the value is committed to textField.

While debugging I noticed the below outcome:

1. When window focus is lost, it turns of focus on all child nodes.
2. ComboBoxPopupControl calls a method **setTextFromTextFieldIntoComboBoxValue** when focus is lost. At this point if you look at the value in the method, the textField's text is empty and the '*value*' is null resulting in setting null value to the  comboBoxBase(highlighted line).

[image]
I think we can tweak this in two ways:

**Option#1:** 
  Taking @Kleopatra solution in another way,i.e, by setting the text just before showing alert. This way we are fooling the **ComboBoxPopupControl**->**setTextFromTextFieldIntoComboBoxValue**  method that there is a valid value in textField and not let it to reset the value.

**Option#2:**
 Wrap the part of the showing alert in **Platform.runLater**, to process the the alert showing at later point in execution (by that time the commit will be already performed in DatePicker).

This worked for both manually entered dates and dates selected in popup.

Not sure if this work around is suitable for you. Can you give a try?

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.DatePicker;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.time.LocalDate;

public class DatePickerCommit extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        // Simple Interface
        VBox root = new VBox(10);
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(10));

        DatePicker datePicker = new DatePicker();

        // Add listener on DatePicker
        datePicker.valueProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            if (newValue != null) {
                // Option#1
               datePicker.getEditor().setText(datePicker.getConverter().toString(newValue));
               showAlert(newValue);

               // Option#2
               //Platform.runLater(()->showAlert(newValue));
            }
        });

        root.getChildren().add(datePicker);

        // Show the stage
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Sample");
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private void showAlert(LocalDate value){
        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.WARNING);
        alert.setContentText("You selected " + value);
        alert.show();
        alert.setY(alert.getY()+100);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Sai. This is a great work around and works perfectly in my situation.

Comment: Added more insights into this.

Answer (score 1):

Basically it's a unwanted [side-effect of a bug fix](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8136838) to support commitOnFocusLost on ComboBox and DatePicker that was accidentally (?) [reverted by another bug fix](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8150946) to support consistent commit-cancel api on ComboBox et al and Spinner which "forgot" to add the commit-cancel api on DatePicker leading to a [regression of the original bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8191995) for DatePicker with the benefit of not having the unwanted side-effect :)

To hack around, you can add your own support for commit-on-focusLost similarly to what is done for ComboBox/Spinner, that is by adding a focusListener to the DatePicker and update the editor from the picker's value (beware: not formally tested!)

```
datePicker.focusedProperty().addListener((src, ov, nv) -> {
    if (!nv) {
        datePicker.getEditor().setText(datePicker.getConverter().toString(datePicker.getValue()));
    }
});
```

Comment: I use this: `datePicker.valueProperty().bindBidirectional((Property<LocalDate>) datePicker.getEditor().getTextFormatter().valueProperty());` because there is also a problem with the popup refresh if the date is entered manually.

Comment: @mrmcwolf is correct that your solution does not account for manually-entered dates (those will revert back once the `DatePicker` loses focus.  Unfortunately, his suggestion is also not usable as it leads to an NPE.

Comment: @Zephyr, My decision counts as a popup choice (updates `TextField::textProperty` built into the control) and updates `valueProperty` when editing manually. The reason for returning the old values is in the `TextFormatter` and the way it handles exceptions in the used `StringConverter::fromString`.

Comment: uups .. guilty of not checking the manual input (blinded by the regression;) @mrmcwolf sounds reasonable, you might consider posting your approach as an answer:)

Answer (score 0):

The "problem" with restoring old values is the implementation of the used `TextFormatter`, which converts the string value of the text field used in the control.

To solve this problem, I use my own `StringConverter`, which provides a value for resetting the date (*null* or *empty string*). All other strings are converted to `LocalDate`, with invalid ones causing the `DateTimeParseException` exception, which causes the `TextFormatter` used to restore the last valid entered date.

All that remains is to associate the `valueProperty`'s of the `DatePicker` and `TextFormatter` used.

Here is an example implementation:

```
StringConverter<LocalDate> converter = new StringConverter<LocalDate>() {
    private final DateTimeFormatter FORMATTER = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy");

    @Override
    public String toString(LocalDate object) {
        if(object == null) return "";

        return object.format(FORMATTER);
    }

    @Override
    public LocalDate fromString(String string) {
        if(string == null || string.isEmpty()) return null;

        return LocalDate.parse(string, FORMATTER);
    }
};

datePicker.setConverter(converter);
datePicker.getEditor().setTextFormatter(new TextFormatter<>(converter));
datePicker.valueProperty().bindBidirectional(
        (Property<LocalDate>) datePicker.getEditor().getTextFormatter().valueProperty()
);
```

Comment: Unfortunately this solution does not work when selecting a value from the popup.

Comment: shared downvotes are half downvotes <g> Fair enough, though, because none of our approaches fixes it for all. Probably need to be combined somehow: expect lots of work, which I don't deem worth any effort, as fx8 is quite outdated. On the other hand: it will bubble up in later versions as soon as the regression (of not committing at all) is fixed - expect a clean solution being possible in core, though, seems to have been successful for comboBox, afaict.

Comment: @kleopatra - I will have to choose the most user-friendly "fix," I suppose. Since my target audience seems averse to keyboards in general, I'll side with the answer that fixes the popup selection at least. :P

Comment: Would like to update the Java version used, but as the only developer of this enterprise-level beast of an application, I'm stuck with 8 for now.